# Activity That has Several Extras from Other Activities?

Tags: android

I have an Activity that uses the following code to retrieve information from another activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int tok = extras.getInt("Token");
        tempToken += tok;
    }
```

This is the Code inside the first other class that sends this information:

```
final Button mainMen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toMainMenu);

    mainMen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Menu.class);
            i.putExtra("Token", tok + teTok);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Now i have another Activity that also wants to sen information to the Main Activity like so:

```
        maMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Campaign.this, Menu.class);
            intent.putExtra("Token", player.tokens);
            intent.putExtra("Round", player.round);
            intent.putExtra("Rank", player.rank);
            intent.putExtra("Score", player.score);
            intent.putExtra("Sec", player.secondsTapped);
            intent.putExtra("Min", player.minutesTapped);
            intent.putExtra("Hour", player.hoursTapped);
            intent.putExtra("Day", player.daysTapped);
            intent.putExtra("LifeTap", player.tapsInLife);
            intent.putExtra("SecTap", player.tapsPerSec);
            intent.putExtra("TapRo", player.tapps);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Now my question is, how do i handle these different extras from multiple Activities inside the one Main Activity?

Thank You for your time :)

Comment: Try to use SharedPreferences, you need to store only once and you can get it in any activities.

Comment: Tip : Instead of putting lot of primitive values into bundle, u can create a class with all these primitives, make an object and send that object to other activity. Its quite efficient, more readable and requires less code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve your problem..

**1)** 
    You can pass one **boolean** value to or and **int** variable with some value.. And retrieve this in your new Activity and check with boolean value or int value and get correct data correspond to Activity.

**2)** You can save your all Data in **Shared Preference**. And get your all Data in any Activity.

Comment: Tip : Instead of putting lot of primitive values into bundle, u can create a class with all these primitives, make an object and send that object to other activity. Its quite efficient, more readable and requires less code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents

Answer (score 0):

you can send one `boolean` value that data is in first class or second class and in `MainActivity` check the value and get the correct data